# Add service reference to ESB toolkit and BizTalk

Tags: web-services, iis, biztalk, esb, esb-toolkit-2.0

I have installed BizTalk together with ESB toolkit and ESB services are up and running according to IIS. I want to connect to these services from a simple WinForm application.

When I try to add this service reference in my project in visual studio
localhost/ESB.BizTalkOperationsService/Operations.asmx

I get the following error message:

> There was an error downloading 'localhost/ESB.BizTalkOperationsService/Operations.asmx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'localhost/ESB.BizTalkOperationsService/Operations.asmx'.
>   The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
>   The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again."

I can browse to:
localhost/ESB.BizTalkOperationsService

but not to the service directly:
localhost/ESB.BizTalkOperationsService/Operations.asmx

How do I communicate with this ESB service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the webservice had been incorrectly installed. I managed to fix this problem by unistalling and reinstalling according to this tutorial

http://geekswithblogs.net/BizTalkUnleashed/archive/2012/11/07/biztalk-server-2013-beta-on-windows-8-visual-studio-2012.aspx